# Flickerfree drawing using gdi+

Tags: c#, drawing, gdi+

I have a .png file i want to draw, the problem is though, i am drawing this png every 1/10th of a second, so that's 10 times per second. This png is being drawn with an X and a Y coordinate as its middle point, so the middle of the image are the X and Y coordinates.

Using this code:

```
private void frmMap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Bitmap FlashLight = new Bitmap(
      Image.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"light.png"), 4000, 2160);
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(FlashLight, new Point(mapX, mapY));
}
```

the problem is though, when drawing this png 10 times per second, with changing X and Y coordinates results in alot of flicker.

Does anyone have any idea on how to reduce or remove the flicker? I have looked into drawing the bitmap off screen and loading it once its done drawing, i have no clue how to do this.

I have also looked into double buffering, which again i have no clue on how to use this to reduce my flicker.

Comment: Looks like you are painting onto a Form. It has a property `DoubleBuffered`, which is the first step. But don't hope for too much; using Winforms for animation is rather limited..

Comment: Also, you are reloading the bitmap on every paint iteration. That is beyond wasteful. Do it only once.

Comment: @TaW What would you recommend using for this animation? Because i just redraw the png at a new location, but the problem with the redrawing is that the screen goes white, and the whole png gets redrawn. It doesnt have to be a fluent animation, it can be chunky, but just not flickering so much

Comment: Instead of doing any drawing you could move a (best buffered) control that shows the image. See my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Winforms` is definitely not well suited for animation.

Here is a suggestion, you may or may not find good enough:

Load the large `Image` into a `PictureBox.Image` and set the `PictureBox.SizeMode = AutoSize`.

Then in your animation `Timer.Tick` you move the `PictureBox` around.

Here is a tiny example:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 100;
timer.Tick += timer_Tick;

// when the timer runs..
timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled;
```

..it moves the `PictureBox` around:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = new Point(pictureBox1.Left + offsetX, pictureBox1.Top + offsetY);
    pictureBox1.Location = pt;
}
```

Note that the location can go into the negative without any problem!

To center the initial location of the image use:

```
pictureBox1.Location = new Point(-(pictureBox1.Width - Width)/2, 
                                 -(pictureBox1.Height - Height)/2);
```

For much better animation support you may consider using WPF.

Comment: im pretty noob at this stuff atm, so this question may sound really stupid but what do you mean with offsetX and offsetY

Comment: because i know what youre doing, but i need to give in (known) X and Y coordinates that need to be the starting point of the picturebox were moving or even better the middle point of the picturebox

Comment: you want to move the image, right? so you need to change its location by some amount. that's what the two variables are for. To center the intial location you would calculate like this pb.left= -(pb.width - form.width) / 2; etc..

Comment: Good. As I wrote this should be a lot better than your original code but for truely smooth movement you would have to learn WPF.

Comment: ye well seeing im only getting 10 x,y coordinates per second, it cant be smooth anyway,

Comment: Yes, but beyond this limit for truely smooth movement you would need to display in synch with the monitor and for all practical purposes winforms can't do that.